# IoT Edge Offline Data Storage decoding .log data file

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I have mounted local storage to my Edge Hub/Agent Modules, and when the device goes offline it stores the data locally. In the event that the device cant go up online, I need to be able to read the offline data and send it to IoT hub. After looking at the file, some portion of the message is base64 encoded, and some parts have non-base64 encoded characters.

Is there a method for decoding the message or any architecture patterns to support cases when a device can't go back up online and upload the data?

Comment: afaik the data is stored in a RocksDB. So I would guess that's what the format is. I don't think reading the data "manually" is supported but I would assume it should be technically doable by looking into how RocksDB works